# Getting/reading res.status() value from Express server response

Tags: node.js, express, express-4

We can the response code with:

```
res.status(v);
```

but later on for the same request, how can we check to see if it has been set? I am looking at the Express docs and not seeing how to do something like:

```
res.getStatus() // => 500
```

Comment: `res.statusCode`?

Comment: thanks I will try it, is it mentioned in the express docs? Idk

Comment: Nope. I found this prop by `console.log(res)`. As you can see this prop doesn't have any "private" mark e.g. `_statusCode` or `statusCode_`. So used it is not "hack".

Comment: add an answer and I will accept/upvote thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`res.statusCode` is the answer and this is a core Node.js thing, it's not particular to Express.

Comment: not working for me. also tried res.statusCode(), not working either. it's also not mentioned in the express.js docs

Comment: @mallocthePD Seems like `res.status(code)` might be what you're looking for [API Routes Response Helpers](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/response-helpers)

Answer (score 4):

According to Aikon Mogwai you can use `res.statusCode`.

I tried it and it works!! (in express 4.16)